# $m^k-k^m=17$ find solutions.

Tags: number-theory

Find all solution to the equation 
$m^k-k^m=17$  where $m,k\ge 2$ and  are positive integers.
I have analysed the equation by $mod(3) $  but I didn't get anything.

Comment: You might try to prove that $|m^k-k^m|>17$ for all but a few small values of $m$ and $k$. Anyway, have you found any solutions?

Comment: For example , m=18,k=1

Comment: @Gerry Myerson For $k=m+1$, by digital roots theory, on which I have done some research, I have got a solution $k=4, m=3$

Comment: @user121270 $m,k\ge2$  and we can not conclude which values will give greater difference, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider when $k>m$. Let's $f(m,k)=m^k-k^m$.

1. $k=m+1$

   $g(m)=f(m,m+1)=m^{m+1}-(m+1)^m$,$g(2)=-1,g(3)=17,g(4)=1024-625>17,g(5)>17,...$
2. $k=m+2$
   $g(m)=f(m,m+2)=m^{m+2}-(m+2)^m$,$g(2)=0,g(3)>17,g(4)>17,g(5)>17,...$
3. $k=m+3$

   $g(m)=f(m,m+3)=m^{m+3}-(m+3)^m$,$g(2)=7,g(3)>17,g(4)>17,g(5)>17,...$
4. $k=m+4$

   $g(m)=f(m,m+4)=m^{m+4}-(m+4)^m$,$g(2)>17,g(3)>17,g(4)>17,g(5)>17,...$

.....
So I think for $k>m$ your solution the only solution.

Comment: Is it a perfect solution?  I don't think so....

Comment: No,It is not perfect,only case $k>m$.